# I am trying to move a folder to rewrite over the contents of another folder for a forum upgrade

Tags: command-line

I need help moving just the contents of the folder over to another folder overwriting any similar folders. I am using the linux terminal SSH.

I don't want to move the folder itself only the contents of the folder overwriting the contents of another folder.

Answer (score 1):

I transfered it all by hand using

cp /sourcefolder/nameoffileordirectory /destinationfoler/

cp -r for the directories

Answer (score 0):

If the destination directory already exists and you don't want to copy the *source* into the destination directory, using the option `-T` will copy the content of the source into the destination, rather than copying the *source* itself.

```
$ cp -T source/ target/
'source/a' -> 'target/a'
```